# Bad math environment delimiter. \mathcal{K} = \[

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, delimiters

I'm getting this error, please help me fix it.
here's my code :

```
    \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:4}
    \mathcal{K} = \[\frac{A}{B}\]
    \end{equation}
```

Comment: thanks @HenriMenke, this solves my problem. Could you please solve my another problem, when I write N - 1 inside \begin{equation}..., it gives output N1 why it is not writing - sign?

Comment: @GaurishGangwar Check you're using `-` (ASCII hyphen) and not some Unicode character.

Comment: @egreg , actually when I write $N-1$ it shows right, but when I write - (the value for $N − 1$ machines in $m − 1$ stages) + (the value for $N − 1$ machines in $m$ stages), Now it show wrong output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\begin{equation}` is already in math mode, so `\[` and `\]` are unnecessary.

Just use:

```
 \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:4}
    \mathcal{K} = \frac{A}{B}
 \end{equation}
```

**Edit:**
As Henri said you can use `\left[` and `\right]` if you want brackets.

Comment: Yes, I wanted brackets. Thanks for answering.